# Директива RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает `.*` после директивы `RewriteRule` и какая разница между `.*` и `(.*)`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/dir/test.php$
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.* это регулярное выражение которое анализирует ваш url. точка означает любой символ, * повторение от 0 до бесконечности. По сути .* любое количество любых символов (все возможные запросы).  Круглые скобки используются в регулярных выражениях для группировки условий. В данном случае никакой разницы в себе не несут. В других ситуациях можно обращаться к группам через знак $

Например правило

RewriteRule ^search /(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1

преобразует запрос search/qwerty в /search.php?q=qwerty

Comment: Евгений, спасибо за ответ. Скажите, пожалуйста, почему если вместо `RewriteRule .* - [F,L]` написать `RewriteRule /dir/test.php - [F,L]`, то правило перестаёт работать?